# Iterate the arguments in shell script ( arguments sent as a list from python file )

Tags: python, shell, sh

I have tried below:

```
param_list = ("hi ", "life", "jam", "hello")

print param_list

subprocess.call(shlex.split('./test.sh *param_list'))
```

In my shell script, I want to loop through the list that I passed:

```
#!/bin/sh


for i in $*; do
  echo $i
done
```

But the above code prints *param_list not the ("hi ", "life", "jam", "hello").
Can someone help me with this requirement !!

Comment: Why do you expect `*param_list` to evaluate to anything other than `*param_list`? If you just want to pass the arguments, then you don't need `shlex` at all: `subprocess.call(["./test.sh", *param_list])`. As a side note, [you should stop using python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

Comment: Since `param_list` is _inside_ the quotes, it is treated as a literal string, not a variable name.

Comment: Can you please share sample code how to achieve above requirement? @JohnGordon if I just send param_list as argument , it treats as it a single argument and returns param_list as answer. i want  this as the answer "hi ", "life", "jam", "hello"

Comment: Hint: Put an `echo` before a shell line to see what the shell turns it into, like e.g. wildcard replacement and variable substitution.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt "How to pass a list instead of a string to the shell script as arguments" this is my question. Thank you

Comment: You are passing a list, I believe, or maybe a tuple. What does `shlex.split` return?

Comment: @Anusha You don't. You either construct a single string for the shell to parse, or you construct a list to be passed directly to `execve`, bypassing the shell altogether.

Comment: Shells don't have lists; you pass a series of individual string arguments instead.

Answer (score 0):

Others have discussed the python side. For the shell, you need to use

```sh
for arg in "$@"; do
```

which will iterate over the args precisely as given, without being affected by word splitting or filename expansion.

To see the difference, try this:

```sh
# set positional parameters
set -- "first arg" "second arg" "*"

# Now, echo the args
for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; done

# versus
for word in $*; do echo "$word"; done
```

Comment: I am concerned only "How to pass a list instead of a string to the shell script as arguments". I am able to achieve the above using my shell code.  Thank you !